# Bayes rule with multiple tests

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Say you are given the following

\begin{align*}
P(cancer) &= 0.008,            & P(\neg cancer) &= 0.992\\
P(\oplus|cancer) &= 0.98,      & P(\ominus|cancer) &= 0.02\\
P(\oplus|\neg cancer) &= 0.03, & P(\ominus|\neg cancer) &= 0.97
\end{align*}

and you test a patient to see if they have cancer or not and it returns positive. If the patient wants to be tested another time, and it once again returns positive, what happens to the probability that the patient has cancer after testing a second time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Bayes' Theorem,
\begin{align*}
P(\text{cancer} \mid \oplus \& \oplus) &= \frac{P(\text{cancer} \cap \oplus \& \oplus)}{P(\oplus \& \oplus)}\\
&= \frac{P(\oplus \& \oplus \mid \text{cancer})P(\text{cancer})}{P(\oplus \& \oplus \mid \text{cancer})P(\text{cancer})+P(\oplus \& \oplus \mid \neg\text{cancer})P(\neg\text{cancer})}
\end{align*}
Now we have to make some assumptions about the two tests, and I think it is reasonable to assume their outcomes are independent. E.g., if someone has cancer, then the second test is positive with $98\%$ chance regardless of the first test. Then we can say:
$$P(\oplus \& \oplus \mid \text{cancer})=P(\oplus \mid \text{cancer})P(\oplus \mid \text{cancer})$$
and similarly
$$P(\oplus \& \oplus \mid \neg\text{cancer})=P(\oplus \mid \neg\text{cancer})P(\oplus \mid \neg\text{cancer}).$$
You should be able to finish from here.

Comment: What does $\oplus \& \oplus$ stand for?

Comment: Sorry, that means the first test came out positive and the second test came out positive.

Comment: So the result is $\frac{0.98^2 \cdot 0.008}{0.98^2 \cdot 0.008 + 0.03^2 \cdot 0.992}$?

Comment: Yes. Again, as I (and the answer answer) noted, this is assuming the outcome of the second test is conditionally independent of the outcome of the first test. This was not stated in the problem, but without this information there is no way to know the answer.

Comment: How did we get from \begin{align*}
 \frac{P(\oplus \& \oplus \mid \text{cancer})P(\text{cancer})}{P(\oplus \& \oplus \mid \text{cancer})P(\text{cancer})+P(\oplus \& \oplus \mid \neg\text{cancer})P(\neg\text{cancer})}
\end{align*} to $$P(\oplus \& \oplus \mid \text{cancer})=P(\oplus \mid \text{cancer})P(\oplus \mid \text{cancer})$$

Comment: The second does not follow from the first. It follows from the assumption that each test outcome is conditionally independent given the cancer status. You would then plug those quantities back into the first equation to solve.

Comment: @kccu, hope you'er still around — was hoping to get a clarification from you. I follow everything you've got until we reach the point of 

(⊕&⊕∣cancer)(cancer) +  (⊕&⊕∣¬cancer)(¬cancer). 

Would you mind helping me think through why we multiply each of these two conditional probabilities by the probability of having/not having cancer here? I can't quite get my head around this. EDIT: oh duh, because that's just the way of calculating the probability, mentally glossed over that, NEVER MIND! Thanks again for a great answer.

Comment: @scrollex It sounds like you worked it out, but "law of total probability" would be the thing to look up here.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't simply enough information to answer this. Sure, you could think that the results of the two tests are [conditionally independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) given that the patient has a cancer or not. However, in most cases, they are not and usually whoever results positive to a test tend to result positive to other tests whether or not they have a cancer. This because different tests might react to a condition which is highly correlated with the desease.

Say for instance that the presence of a given hormone (or whatever) is highly indicative of a desease (however, someone could have the hormone and be totally healthy and someone else with the desease might not develop the hormone). Then, you have two tests that, with different tecniques, aim to detect the presence of the hormone (both tests might be wrong sometimes). If someone results positive to a test, the presence of the hormone becomes more probable, and consequently, the patient is more likely to have the desease. With the second positive test, the hormone still becomes more likely to be there. However, this won't enhance much the probability that the patient has the desease, since they might be someone of the healthy guys with the hormone.

So, either you state that the tests are conditionally independent (and so the other answer you received can be applied) or you can't respond to your question.